# Connect to LDAP using PrincipalContext in C#

Tags: c#, ssl, ldap, single-sign-on, principalcontext

I am trying to connect to an LDAP server in C# using PrincipalContext. I've validated the network parameters and authentication settings are all correct using Apache Directory Studio. This is the code I'm using:

```
string sDomain = @"vds.myCompany.net:1234";
string sDefaultOU = @"ou=apdev,ou=ads,o=vds";
string sUser = @"myUsername";
string sPassword = @"myPassword";

ContextOptions options = ContextOptions.SimpleBind | ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer;
PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, sDomain, null, options, sUser, sPassword);
```

I must connect using SSL and my credentials are SSO. I've tried with and without specifying the sDefaultOU as the container parameter. The error it throws at the last line is:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.ReadServerConfig(String
>   serverName, ServerProperties& properties)    at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext.DoServerVerifyAndPropRetrieval()
>   at
>   System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType
>   contextType, String name, String container, ContextOptions options,
>   String userName, String password)

Comment: Do you have `SSL` installed? Does your user has enough rights? Try simply binding without specifying `username` and `password`.  `PrincipalContext context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, sDomain)`.

Comment: How would I know if I have SSL installed? I can connect successfully via Apache Directory Studio and Pentaho.

Comment: Here's what I get when I try binding without user/pw: System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.DirectoryOperationException: The server is unavailable.
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.ConstructResponse(Int32 messageId, LdapOperation operation, ResultAll resultType, TimeSpan requestTimeOut, Boolean exceptionOnTimeOut)
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequest(DirectoryRequest request, TimeSpan requestTimeout)
   at System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.LdapConnection.SendRequest(DirectoryRequest request)

Comment: Ask you sys admin if `SSL` installed. But to check it yourself, set your `ContextOptions` just to `ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer`. If you don't have it's going to throw a message. Unless you changed it, the default port is `636`. You're connecting to `1234` Is that intentionally?

Comment: Setting ContextOptions just to ContextOptions.SecureSocketLayer throw this error: System.ArgumentException: The ContextOptions passed are invalid for this store type.  Either Negotiate or SimpleBind must be specified and they cannot be combined.
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType contextType, String name, String container, ContextOptions options, String userName, String password)
   at System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext..ctor(ContextType contextType, String name, String container, ContextOptions options)

Comment: I'm not connecting to 636 or 1234, I'm just not allowed to post the actual port number.

Comment: That's what I was expecting to see. This message `The ContextOptions passed are invalid for this store type` tells you you don't have `SSL` installed. I'm guessing you're using `389` which is not secure. To connect without SSL you can use `PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "yourdomian.com", container, ContextOptions.SimpleBind);`